# ImportError: No module named 'speech_recognition' in python IDLE

Tags: python, module, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm trying to use the speech recognition module with python 3.5.1 to make my jarvis AI voice activated! I have looked through stack overflow and found some questions similar to mine but they did not have the answer that i needed, i need an answer individualized for this. I have downloaded all the necessary packages and still no luck, i get this error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'speech_recognition'
```

If I run:

```
python -m speech_recognition
```

In terminal it runs only in terminal, i can talk to it and it isn't nearly spot on but it hears me and and can interpret some words. I have downloaded all the packages in terminal from this sites instructions.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/

When i run my code in IDLE my code gets the error shown above. I'm on a iMac running macOS Sierra 10.12.2,
if anyone has the answer that would be helpful. 
Thank you!

heres my code:

```
import speech_recognition
import pyttsx

speech_engine = pyttsx.init('sapi5') # see         
speech_engine.setProperty('rate', 150)

def speak(text):
   speech_engine.say(text)
   speech_engine.runAndWait()

recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()

def listen():
    with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)

    try:
        return recognizer.recognize_sphinx(audio) 
        # or: return recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
    except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:
        print("Could not understand audio")
    except speech_recognition.RequestError as e:
        print("Recog Error; {0}".format(e))

    return ""



speak("Say something!")
speak("I heard you say " + listen())
```

Comment: Is IDLE running the same version of Python that you run when you start Python from the terminal?

Comment: no your right so how do i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OS X Sierra [comes with Python 2.7.10](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7740214?start=0&tstart=0). Since you are using Python 3.5.1, you have presumably installed it yourself and you now have two versions of Python. IDLE is clearly running with the Python version for which you did *not* install the `speech_recognition` module.

What to do depends on your set-up. I'd start by running `idle3` from the command line, instead of `idle`. If your module is installed for Python 3, that's all you need. If this doesn't work, check everything with an eye to the different versions and straighten them out the way you want them.

Comment: wait how would i go at running IDLE 3 in the terminal?

Comment: i figured it out i wrote: python3 -m speech_recognition in terminal

Comment: what do i do now i can't downgrade python to 2.7.10 can i?

Comment: can i use pip3 to install it now, i tried and it says You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command. so i update and then it say Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg

Comment: Thank you, you have diagnosed the problem but how do i fix it?

Comment: If it works when you type `python3 -m speech_recognition`, you have already installed it for Python 3; so don't worry about `pip3`, you don't need that anymore. To launch IDLE 3, type `idle3` or `idle3 <scriptname.py>` (lowercase) at the terminal.

Comment: Ok but when i type in (python3 -m speech_recognition) it gives the error: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3: No module named speech_recognition. if i run (pip3 install SpeechRecognition)   to download it for python 3, it gives me the error: (error: could not create '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/speech_recognition': Permission denied)                                    You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 9.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: Then I update the pip with (pip install --upgrade pip) and it says its already up to date?!?!?!: Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg

Comment: I need help ;( i feel hopeless (and when it works in terminal the code can barely understand what i'm saying. When i say "now" it thinks i'm say "no" and vise versa and when i say "what's up" it thinks i'm say WhatsApp almost always. How do you get it to understand you is that what some of those other modules are for, like the pocket sphinx one what does that do does that help it understand you??

Comment: I'm afraid I know nothing about python's speech recognition modules-- and it's a different question, so you should write a new question to conform with the rules of the site. Make sure to make it as specific as possible, phrase it so that it's about programming, and **not** to ask for a software recommendation-- that's not permitted.

Comment: Anyway speech recognition is a hard problem. You get better performance with models you can "train" to your voice, often by reading aloud known texts. But don't be surprised if the little free module you downloaded and run from your script doesn't give you usable performance.

Comment: ok thank you Alexis i will keep it in mind, and i will ask another question.

Answer (score 26):

Install Speech Recognition using

`pip install SpeechRecognition`

Answer (score 5):

I upgraded my python to 3.7 in mac, but then I was facing similar issue.

`pip3 install SpeechRecognition`

this worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Try this in windows command prompt for python 3.7 32 bit

```
python -m pip install -U pip

pip install winspeech

pip install SpeechRecognition
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Try This it will work! I had faced the same problem.

```
 pip install SpeechRecognition
```

Answer (score 1):

for python3 try running the command to install the SpeechRecognition module:
pip3 install SpeechRecognition

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33088508)

Answer (score 0):

In may case the error was - No module named speechRecognition
incase that's the case with you try editing the import code and use
import speech_recognition as sr
It worked for me. Sometimes pip gives these issues

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have all the requirements listed in the “Requirements”:

Install Xcode in Unix Development mode.
Install Xcode - Command Line tools (Type 'Xcode-select —install' in the terminal )

**

```
Install Port or Brew (port  [or] Brew  )
sudo brew install portaudio [or] sudo port install portaudio (for loading mic drivers)
sudo pip install pyaudio [or] sudo easy_install install pyaudio (Mic Sources)
sudo pip install SpeechRecognition [or] sudo easy_install install SpeechRecognition
sudo port install FLAC.
```

**

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.
I just installed SpeechRecognition in project properties.
Settings -> Project:(nameofyourproject)->
Python: Interpreter. Click on plus and find SpeechRecognition, install it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

in pychaem tap the hint(alt+enter) and tap install packages while select the package or tap F2 to take to it .

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was, I installed  jupyter notebooks again and on anaconda prompt and then I executed
**pip install SpeechRecognition**

followed by

**pip install PyAudio-0.2.11-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl**

again.

Comment: The OP states he is using macOS, so your advice to install a win_amd64 wheel is puzzling.

Comment: My bad. He can rather install -- brew install portaudio, followed by 
python3 -m pip install pyaudio

Answer (score -3):

user must be root
so use

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

It will work.