# ImportError: No module named speech_recognition

Tags: python, mlmodel

Getting **ImportError: No module named speech_recognition**,
Code Snippet:

```
# for speech-to-text
import speech_recognition as sr

# for text-to-speech
from gtts import gTTS

# for language model
import transformers

import os
import time

# for data
import os
import datetime
import numpy as np
```

**I have already tried** `pip3 install SpeechRecognition` **and** `pip install SpeechRecognition`

```
pip3 install SpeechRecognition
Requirement already satisfied: SpeechRecognition in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (3.8.1)
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I am using Python 3.8

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'speech\_recognition' in python IDLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41797920/importerror-no-module-named-speech-recognition-in-python-idle)

Comment: I have tried the solutions of the mentioned link(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41797920/importerror-no-module-named-speech-recognition-in-python-idle), but it didn't work

Comment: Maybe you can try to create a new conda [environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands), install the only needed packages and try again. The reason that I'm saying this is because the issue feels like it's about confusion of some packages. Conda can help with a fresh start.

Comment: Are you running your program using the `python3` executable right?